# Power BI changing data format - Beginner question

Tags: powerbi

**Question 1**
I have excel columns with name 2020M01 2020M02 2019M12 etc

I want to change this into 2020 01 or 2020 Jan

How can I achieve this within Power BI as Excel will not be able to format

**Question 2**
I have Excel source file with columns like below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrnsC.png)

I want Power BI to transform this in below format
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIRsl.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow It is not recommended to ask several questions in one. Better to split it to multiple questions with more specific titles. Then it will be easier for other users to find your questions and answer them.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your questions are best solved in power query.

**question 1**: Assuming the divider "M" is consistent you can use power query to clean the data.

example step (it will be easier if you google replace value power query and power query change data type) ->

#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type","M"," ",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"*****ColumnName*****"}),

#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value",{{"***Column Name***", type date}})

after this you can load the data and format the date as you would in excel via the format drop down.

**question 2**

you need to unpivot the tables then append them.

in power query, select the column then under the transform tab select unpivot. once you have done this for both tables, append them by selecting the append option which is in the home tab (far right).